# iOS - UIbutton image constraints relations with other object

Tags: swift, uibutton, constraints, ios-autolayout

So I have the view below:
[image: view]

I have the plus button with an image(vector) and I am trying to make the auto button to be as the same size(top and bottom) as the plus button, but as you can see the plus button hight change according to the auto button.

If I will put the image in the background of the button we will see it as the button:
[image]

What do I need to do in order to fix the hight of the auto button to be as the same as the plus button?